# nginx 302 redirect to file not updating

Tags: nginx, configuration, cache

We have a Debian 9.4 box running nginx 1.10.3.  The purpose of the box is to provide redirects to files and resources so that Marketing can provide links in their materials, where the underlying content can be pointed at another asset if the document is updated.  That way, customers are always accessing the correct version for reference.

Even though we set it up to be as basic as possible, we are seeing odd behavior that looks like caching.  We can change what the redirect points to, but it continues to resolve to the old version.

For reference, here's our site config:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name files.oursite.com;

    index index.html;

    error_page 404 http://files.oursite.com/error.html;

    location / {
      try_files $uri $redirect;
    }

    location @redirect {
      include /home/fileserve/redirect.conf;
    }
```

Inside redirect.conf, this would appear:

```
rewrite /foo http://files.oursite.com/foo.pdf redirect;
```

That'll work fine.  but if we update it to this:

```
rewrite /foo http://files.oursite.com/bar.pdf redirect;
```

foo.pdf still pops up.

The header response from nginx shows it is still serving foo.pdf, and I've tried it from multiple machines, browsers, and network connections to verify it's not caching under any local circumstances.  This is also after I have switched to 302s from 301s, because we do NOT want local caching.

Does anyone know what is happening, and how to resolve this?  Thanks!

Edit: Adding troubleshooting as requested:

nginx -t syntax ok and test was successful.
nginx -T shows the redirect loading (/foo should redirect to /bar.pdf)
curl as follows:

curl -i http://files.oursite.com/foo:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: nginx
Date: Fri, 25 Jan 2019 18:18:36 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 154
Connection: keep-alive
Location: http://files.oursite.com/bar.pdf
```

curl -I output directly to the files, per @Richard Smith:

for the old file (foo.pdf):

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Fri, 25 Jan 2019 18:39:12 GMT
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Length: 980444
Last-Modified: Tue, 20 Nov 2018 18:10:25 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "5bf44e11-ef5dc"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

for the new file (bar.pdf):

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Fri, 25 Jan 2019 18:39:45 GMT
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Length: 5948805
Last-Modified: Thu, 24 Jan 2019 23:23:50 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "5c4a4906-5ac585"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

Curl -I after adding expires -1;

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: nginx
Date: Fri, 25 Jan 2019 20:42:59 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 154
Connection: keep-alive
Location: http://files.oursite.com/foo.pdf
Expires: Fri, 25 Jan 2019 20:42:58 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

The most difficult part in all of this is remembering to wipe my URLs :)

Comment: Have you restarted Nginx after changing the include file? Does `nginx -t` show no errors? Does `nginx -T` show the new rewrite rule? Have you tested the rule using `curl -I`?

Comment: Richard, I added your instructions in the OP.  Thanks!

Comment: Clearly the redirect has been updated. Are you using cloudflare? What does `curl -I http://files.oursite.com/foo.pdf` say about caching and expiry dates?

Comment: Not using cloudflare.  This is a very low traffic device, so it's only running on a single instance.  I've never seen anything like this.

I updated OP once more.  Thanks again!

Comment: Richard, I've also read through some other similar posts, and I feel like I should mention the instance is located on Digital Ocean.

Comment: My guess is that in the absence of any “Expires” or “Cache-Control” headers in the PDF document's HTTP response, the browsers are using built-in default values. Can you change your file servers response headers to explicitly disable browser caching? I see it's also Nginx, adding `expires -1;` should help.

Comment: Done and added above.  I'm doing the curls directly from the server, fyi.

Comment: I was rather thinking that the `expires -1;` needs to be added to the other server.

Comment: My apologies.  The redirects we're dealing with are pointing to the same server.  Technically, the links are http://www.oursite.com/direct/foo.pdf.  The direct folder contains the files in question we're dealing with.

We're able to resolve the direct links, no problem.  But it's the redirect that seems to be stuck, if that makes sense.

Comment: So the 200 responses also have the "no-cache" headers? Does that help with the caching problem?

Comment: No help.  The old file and the new file show the no-cache headers, but the actual redirect 302's to the old file.

Comment: I can also verify that in nginx.conf, sendfile is set to off.  I know this is a problem on some VPS.

Comment: I've also deleted the redirect from the conf, restarted nginx, and it still resolves.  I've piped output to a txt and the actual link is not in nginx -T!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out the answer, but someone may want to add clarity as to why this is happening.

My redirect file actually has the following:

```
rewrite /foo http://files.oursite.com/foo.pdf redirect;
rewrite /foo-EXAMPLE http://files.oursite.com/foo-EXAMPLE.pdf redirect;
```

For whatever reason, typing /foo-EXAMPLE always picks up the redirect for /foo.  This would explain why no matter the changes I make to /foo-EXAMPLE, it picks up /foo.pdf.  If I delete /foo from the redirect file, /foo-EXAMPLE works correctly.

It also seems that the -EXAMPLE can be prepended to any url, and it'll still grab /foo.  I have no idea why.

Comment: Flagging as solved, and moving this to a different, separate question.